# Load JSON into Grafana

Tags: grafana

I'm brand new to Grafana. Can I (and how) load a JSON into Grafana and display as a table? Or is it only for time series data?

I'm loading grafana with:

```
docker run -d \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --name=grafana \
  -e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-simple-json-datasource" \
  grafana/grafana
```

For example:

```
[{
  "hostname": "1.2.3.4"
}, {
  "hostname": "2.3.4.5"
}, {
  "hostname": "3.4.5.6"
}]
```

Display that as:

| hostname |
| --- |
| 1.2.3.4 |
| 2.3.4.5 |
| 3.4.5.6 |

If I can achieve that (which is the scope of this post),ultimately I want to load 2x tables in and diff them to show a third (calculated) table which includes the items in table 1 but NOT table 2.

For example, if table 2 is:

| hostname |
| --- |
| 2.3.4.5 |
| 3.4.5.6 |

Then table 3 would be:

| hostname |
| --- |
| 1.2.3.4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana is just a visualisation tool. It needs a data source to query data and display. It is optimised for time series data, but static data can also be displayed easily.

Use the [API plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/simpod-json-datasource/) .

You can also use [TestData DB](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/testdata/) data source which is available within Grafana to test scenarios. (does not use json though)

Once the data source is configured, you can use [table panel](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/table/) to display data based on queries.

Each dashboard can have multiple panels so tables can be shown side by side.